# Mysql query to get records between from and to columns with two date inputs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a parking table where i have 'parking_from' and 'parking_to' Timestamp columns. I have a report form where i have 'From' and 'To' filters where user can choose two timestamps to filter any vehicle which might be parked. I tried the following...

```
 select * from parking 
 where parking_from >= '$selected_parking_from' 
   and parking_to <= '$selected_parking_to'
```

but this gives only the vehicle parking starts and ends within the selected date range. But i need to see the parking if any portion of that parking duration falls under the selected range.

Can someone help me how to modify this query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for overlapping intervals.  Two intervals overlap if the first starts before the second *ends* and ends after the second *starts*.

So:

```
select p.*
from parking p
where p.parking_from < '$selected_parking_to' and
      p.parking_to > '$selected_parking_from';
```

Note:  You should be passing in the user's inputs using *parameters*, not by munging the string using variables.  So I would expect something like this:

```
where p.parking_from < ? and
      p.parking_to > ?;
```

Answer (score -1):

If we break your question to its ingredients, we get:
the selected parking from is either before or after the parking_from AND the selected parking to is AFTER the parking_from 
OR
the selected parking to is either before or after the parking_to AND the selected parking from is BEFORE the parking_to

Now we just need to write it...

```
    select * from parking where

( '$selected_parking_from' <= parking_to AND '$selected_parking_from' >= parking_to) OR
( '$selected_parking_to' >= parking_from AND  '$selected_parking_from' <= parking_from) 
;
```

Comment: Close... but no cigar

Comment: @Strawberry fixed it

Comment: You were nearly there. You just had to change OR to AND

Comment: why change? there are 3 types of cases, each case I stated include 2 of the 3: either the selected time crosses the parking_from or it crosses the parking_to, the 3rd case, selected time is between, is included in both as I use the equal sign

Comment: Just go back to your original answer, and change the word.

Comment: Well, your old query was so much more elegant, without all this redundancy